# Android screen - different densities, different sizes

Tags: android

I have read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) article about supporting multiple screens.

So for supporting different densities you should put different drawable bitmaps into correct drawable folders. Then android should load correct image according to current screen density.

But if I understand it right, lets say you have some bitmap for low dpi (75x75px) and for medium dpi (100x100px). So on larger density, it will fill more pixels than on the smaller one. But result physicall size would be the same but on larger density it is more pixels than on the smaller one. Correct image will be used so there will be good quality across different dpis.

And what if I want to have on larger screens larger images?

Lets say that I want to fill specific part of the screen. For example I want to have an `ImageView` which will have size of 20% of the screens width. I use this code now:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.some_bitmap, null);
float ratio = (float)drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()/drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();

ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
img.getLayoutParams().width = (int)(DISPLAY.widthPixels*0.2f);
img.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(ratio*DISPLAY.widthPixels*0.2f);
```

so I get ratio because a do not want to "stretch" bitmap. Then I am getting screens width using `DisplayMetrics` and I am setting dimensions of some `ImageView`.

I have read I should not use "hard coded pixels" but this is universall across all dpis and all physicall sizes. And should I put different drawables for different densities now? Because I do not care about density now. I just fill certain space of the screen. I do not want to use `dpi` because it is the same aross screens sizes but I want to have it that larger screen larger bitmap would be so I do not want to have "empty" spaces on larger screens. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: "And what if I want to have on larger screens larger images?" -- blend in [other resource set qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) (e.g., `res/drawable-sw640dp-hdpi/`), providing drawable resources for that particular screen size and density combination.

Comment: Yes, this is propably what I need, combination of both. And can I then scale it in code? It should be bigger and so on but if I want to have same part of the screen filled. Or you would let it be?

Comment: "And can I then scale it in code?" -- I don't know why you would need it to be. "if I want to have same part of the screen filled" -- that should be established by whatever you are applying the drawable to (`ImageView`, background of some other `View`, etc.).